# Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Amazon Redshift' : file not found

Tags: r

I am connecting R to Amazon Redshift by running the below code but it is giving me an error "Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Amazon Redshift' : file not found" I am using Mac OS M1. For the connect_redshift function I have package installed

I have installed the ODBC driver correctly, can someone please help me. conn <- connect_redshift ( host = "my_host", database = "database_name", user = "user_name", pass = "password", port = 12345, driver = "Amazon Redshift" )

I have tried looking for the answers but did not had any luck

Comment: See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html#install-odbc-driver-linux

Comment: Getting the same error and followed the instructions at AWS. Did you ever resolve?